# unable to see body text in source code

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape job listings in **Indeed** to count the number of times something is asked for in the qualifications.

Problem is that I'm not able to identify any body text in the source code for certain websites. Is there a way I can overcome this issue?

I'm using `beautifulsoup4` for the task. [Here](https://jobs-te.icims.com/jobs/77373/data-scientist/job?hub=44&mode=job&iis=Job%2BBoard&iisn=Indeed&mobile=false&width=940&height=500&bga=false&needsRedirect=false&jan1offset=-300&jun1offset=-240) is an example of one of these websites.

Comment: Please post what you already tried to do and how.

Comment: When asking for help, you should post some sample code that highlights your progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular site seems to "hide" the actual content of each ad into an iframe, for reasons unknown.

The actual content is available at [this URL](https://jobs-te.icims.com/jobs/77373/data-scientist/job?hub=44&mode=job&iis=Job%2BBoard&iisn=Indeed&mobile=false&width=940&height=500&bga=false&needsRedirect=false&jan1offset=-300&jun1offset=-240&in_iframe=1) (the only difference seems to be an `&in_iframe=1` query parameter added to the URL).

However, do note you can't directly view that URL in your browser, as it detects you're not viewing it via the iframe and redirects you to the framing page.

You can, however, verify that the URL contains the actual content via, say, cURL and grep:

```
$ curl -k "https://jobs-te.icims.com/jobs/77373/data-scientist/job?hub=44&mode=job&iis=Job%2BBoard&iisn=Indeed&mobile=false&width=940&height=500&bga=false&needsRedirect=false&jan1offset=-300&jun1offset=-240&in_iframe=1" | grep quantitative

Daily work will involve performing one or more of the following activities: [...]
```

The general technique of detecting, erm, techniques like this on pages is using your browser's developer tools to look at the requests made (in this case, the subrequest for the iframe) and naturally the DOM tree (the iframe being there).

Hope this helps.